# StringTemplate and ASTs

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, stringtemplate

I'm using StringTemplate to perform a model transformation from one language to several back ends. I'm starting from an hand-generated AST that has class hierarchies for, e.g., types within the language.  My question has to do with translation of complex hierarchies within StringTemplate.  Let's examine translating a Type hierarchy, which is implemented in a class hierarchy that looks something like:

```
class Type { }
class IntType extends Type { ...bitsize for integer here... }
class Boolean extends Type {}
class ArrayType extends Type { ...array dimensions and base type here}
class RecordType extends Type { ...field information here...}
```

Is there any way of doing conditional branching based on type information?  I've seen a lot of examples that do the conditional branching directly in the concrete grammar for a language and the template follows the production, but this is not my situation.  The way I see it there are at least four ways I can do this:

1. Not use StringTemplate at all for complex hierarchies; instead translate directly in Java.  However, this means that my use of templating is pretty minimal: Many of the language features I'd like to translate (parameters, declarations, etc.) each have types, so I'd have to just use templating for "leaf level" elements.
2. "Escape" back into Java using a renderer for the Type objects.  This could lead to situations where I call back to Java using a renderer and then call into another StringTemplate object for rendering the individual types, but I assume that this is o.k.
3. Add recognizers for subtypes to my Java classes that I can use directly in the template and do conditional formatting there.
4. Hack getter/setter methods to build string representations for the objects of interest, e.g.: 
   Add a String getStringTemplateTypeString() to my Type class and then reference it with: 
   type.stringTemplateTypeString

I am sure that there are additional ways to do it as well; there is a lot of flexibility here.  I am currently leaning towards option #2, but I'd like some input from this esteemed community :).  I'd like to do it in a way that is straightforward, local (I don't have to change stuff in a bunch of files when I add additional backends), and clean.

Thanks very much!

Mike

Comment: One issue I'm running in to is that if I use solution #2, I have an issue in that I can't pass in the current indent level, so if I have a complex type, it looks horrible.  So I'm still not sure how best to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding on your problem, a work around could be a combination of 4 and 2 where you have a method which will return the type and you do a conditional if-else block based on it and within the the main template itself call another template. This way, you only need an additional getter in your classes. Let know if this doesn't address your problem.